# angular 4 cookie issue

Tags: angular, session-cookies

[image]I am getting cookies in the response headers but I am not able to store them in the browser cookies since the browser is not saving it automatically. Can someone help me with this?

**Note:** I have already tried `withCredentials:true` and `crossDomain:true` and all other options that are available.

```
this.headers.set("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  this.headers.set("dataType","json");
  this.headers.set('crossDomain','true');
  this.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  this.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
  this.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");

 let options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers,withCredentials: true,params:data});

  this.http.post(this.API_URL+this.BASE_URL+'auth/login/',options).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(document.cookie);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }, error => {
    var display=error.json();
    this.error='* '+display.message;
  });
```

Comment: Are you using any library to set cookies?

Comment: @k11k2 no . I am not using any library

Comment: Please share the code that is supposed to store them.

Comment: Could you add your code how you are getting cookies

Comment: @Tom since the cookie is coming from server side browser is suppose to store it which is not happening . i am seeking for some solution so that i can store it .

Comment: have added my code and screenshot of the api call as well

Comment: I don't know about auto browser save but if you want to store cookie in a browser. At server side it self you need to set(store) the cookie and get the the cookie in angular side by using third party libraries. let me know which one you are using node(server)?

Comment: python flask on the server side @k11k2

Comment: `response.set_cookie('cookie_name',values)` use this may it help to set the cookie from server side. To get that cookie by using third party libraries like [ng2-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies) like `import {Cookie} from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies'`
`Cookie.get('your cookie name')` donno about support for angular4. let me know it help you or not.

Comment: cookie.get will work fine to fetch the cookie from cookie storage. here the issue is i am not able to store the cookie (session cookie) that is coming from server side @k11k2

Comment: As I mention above, did you store cookie in browser at server side? without setting cookie how could you expect browser could have. I'm afraid !

Comment: @k11k2 please look at the image that i have shared . cookie is coming in the response header